# List results by "x Days Old"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with applications, when they've been contacted the "contacted" column is marked with a "1". What I want to do if possible is count how many of the results are up to 3 days old, how many of them are 4-6 days old and how many of them are 7 or more days old. Is this possible in a single query?

```
 __________________________________
| Name | Contacted |    Date       |
 ----------------------------------
| Bob  |      1    |  2016-09-16   |
| Ben  |      1    |  2016-10-03   |
| Sam  |      1    |  2016-10-03   |
```

EDIT:

Using the following:

```
SELECT 
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  = 3 then '3 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  > 6 then  '7 or more days'
end as `days`,
sum( case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  = 3 then 1 
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  between 4 and 6 then 1
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  > 6 then 1
else 0 
end  ) as tot 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY
case  
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  = 3 then '3 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(), `submission_date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
    when datediff( CURDATE(),`submission_date`) > 6 then  '7 or more days'
end ;
```

Then

```
echo '<p>'.$row['tot'].'</p>';
```

I'm getting:

```
0
1
```

Comment: date diff in mysql, may be you are looking that

Comment: Using `SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY, submissiondate) AS oneday` I'm getting a random 16 as the value?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a select case and group by

```
 select 
     case  
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  <= 3 then '3 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  > 6 then  '7 or more days'
      end  as `days`,
    sum( case  
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  <= 3 then 1 
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  between 4 and 6 then 1
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  > 6 then 1
        else 0 
    end  ) as tot 
 from my_table 
 where contacted = 1
 group by 
      case  
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  <= 3 then '3 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(),`date`) > 6 then  '7 or more days'
      end ;
```

In the column `my_result` you should find the string you need

```
   select  concat( 'You have *** ',  sum( case  
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  <= 3 then 1 
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  between 4 and 6 then 1
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  > 6 then 1
        else 0 
    end  ), ' *** New Items more than ' , 
     case  
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  <= 3 then '3 Days old'
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  > 6 then  '7 or more days'
      end ) as my_result 
 from my_table 
 where contacted = 1
 group by 
      case  
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  <= 3 then '3 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(), `date`)  between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days'
        when datediff( CURDATE(),`date`) > 6 then  '7 or more days'
      end ;
```

Comment: With this i'm getting `There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days' when > 6 then '7 or more days' end as days,' at line 5]`

Comment: Missing ) and wrapped date  in backtics  .. answer updated

Comment: I have changed the way for eval the condition  .. i have update the answer

Comment: Wrong date_diff instead of datediff

Comment: Now getting `There was an error running the query [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'between 4 and 6 then '4-6 Days' when date_diff( CURDATE(),date at line 17]`

Comment: Thanks, no error anymore... However do I just use `$row['tot']` to get the results? At the moment that is just showing '0 1' when I have 2 rows from today and 1 that's over 7 days old.

Comment: I have update the answer for <= 3  ..hope is what you are looking for

Comment: That's brilliant and is showing the correct number. How do I now assign these to variables to wrap text around each number?

Comment: I don't understand what in your last comment .. and i think my answer  is right respect to  your question ..   .. seems you are asking somthings new ..

Comment: Using what you've posted I get `1 2` which is the correct number, however I would like to say `You have **1** new item more than 3 days old` if possible?

Comment: I have update the answer .. and hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Is there any way to do this by telling the result a I would like to have a different class applied to each if possible? For example if would like to do something like `if(over 7 days) { echo '<p class="Urgent">'.$row['tot'].'</p>';`

Comment: @BN83   . this is a new question and is not fair change the question time by time .. if my answer is right please rate as useful and mark it as accepted and for new question post a new correctly documented  question ..